# Scala Ambiguous Variable Name Within A Method

Tags: scala, variables, scoping, shadowing

I've seen some questions regarding Scala and variable scoping (such as [Scala variable scoping question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099898/scala-variable-scoping-question))

However, I'm having trouble getting my particular use-case to work.

Let's say I have a trait called Repo:

```
trait Repo {
    val source: String
}
```

And then I have a method to create an implementation of Repo...

```
def createRepo(source: String) = 
  new Repo {
    val source: String = source
  }
```

Of course I have two `source` variables in use, one at the method level and one inside of the `Repo` implementation.  How can I refer to the method-level `source` from within my `Repo` definition?

Thanks!

Comment: Since both refer to the same object, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user-unknown, It does matter because in the second instance, `source`  gets bound "recursively", but class initialization semantics make it `null`. Try it from the REPL and you'll see: `createRepo("hi").source == null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the canonical way, but it works:

```
def createRepo(source: String) = {
  val sourceArg = source
  new Repo {
    val source = sourceArg
  }
}
```

Or, you could just give your paramenter a different name that doesn't clash.

Or, make a factory:

```
object Repo {
  def apply(src: String) = new Repo { val source = src }
}

def createRepo(source: String) = Repo(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solutions of Luigi, you might also consider changing `Repo` from a trait to a class,

```
class Repo(val source: String)
def createRepo(source: String) = new Repo(source)
```